# Android MMS connection ends with unable resolve host

Tags: android, host, mms, resolve

I have app with MMS send feature, based on this http://androidbridge.blogspot.de/2011/03/how-to-send-mms-programmatically-in.html

It works and correct connection (mobile mms network) is established, but on

```
connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
```

I get "error" Unable to resolve host "http://mms"

APN setting is valid (work with build-in sms/mms) a MMS enabled on my phone/sim. Data connection avaible.

APN use proxy, which is set and use in code (and checked in debug info).

What I can check more to find the problem? Every needed variable (username, pass, proxy, url...) is set...

Comment: I Have the exact same question, my unable to resolve host occurs on "http://mms.gprs.rogers.com".  Did you get this issue fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check your Manifest File and add internet permission there.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I just spent a bit of time pulling my hair out until I remembered I did not set permissions.